# How to combine JSON and Handlebars from partials into HTML with Gulp?

Tags: json, gulp, handlebars.js, gulp-compile-handlebars

I'm building a static site using Handlebars and Gulp.  Here's my folder structure:

```
app/
    content/
        intro.json
        header.json
        faq.json
        features.json
        footer.json
    templates/
        home.hbs
        partials/
            home-section.hbs
            header.hbs
            footer.hbs
    index.html
Gulpfile.js
```

The content of home.hbs is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{> header}}
    {{> home-section}}
    {{> home-section}}
    {{> home-section}}
    {{> footer}}
</body>
</html>
```

I want to pass in `intro.json`, `faq.json`, and `features.json` to each of the `home-section` partials, and `header.json` to `header` and `footer.json` to footer.

This is what I have in my Gulpfile so far:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var handlebars = require('gulp-compile-handlebars');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('html', function() {
  return gulp.src('./app/templates/*.hbs')
    .pipe(handlebars({}, {
            ignorePartials: true,
            batch: ['./app/templates/partials']
          }))
    .pipe(rename({
            extname: '.html'
          }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to pass more than one JSON file at a time, especially to the `home-section`s.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first parameter to `handlebars` is your global context, available to all your templates. You can load your individual JSON files into a context object, and use that as the first parameter.

(There's definitely better ways to do this, but hey, it's quick and easy!)

```
var infoData = require('./app/content/info.json');
var faqData = require('./app/content/faq.json');
var featuresData = require('./app/content/features.json');
```

You can then pass these objects through the global context to your handlebars function

```
.pipe(handlebars({ info: infoData, faq: faqData, features: featuresData }))
```

Once the data is inside your context, you can access it like this:

```
{{> home-section content=info }}
{{> home-section content=faq }}
{{> home-section content=features }}
```

Inside your `home-section` partial, you'll have a `content` object that will contain the data of the file you passed into it. So, if your `info.json` file looked like this:

```
{ "header": "Info", "details": "This is some information" }
```

Your `home-content.hbs` partial could then access the data like this:

```
<h2>{{ content.header }}</h2>
<p>{{ content.details }}</p>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'inside your `home-section`, you'll have a `content` object? Can you show me the code for this, please?

Comment: @Ryan When you render a handlebars partial, the parameters you pass into it are then available inside the partial's template based on the name of the parameter you used. So if you inserted your partial with `{{> home-section thing=info }}`, your `home-section` partial would have access to a variable `thing` containing the content of `info`.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, `gulp-compile-handlerbars` function only takes [two arguments](https://github.com/kaanon/gulp-compile-handlebars/blob/master/index.js#L8), the first one being all the data passed into your templates. This means you have to load up all your json files together and pass them as a single object.

You can do this with a small helper like:

```
function requireJsons(fileNames) {
  return fileNames.reduce(function(jsons, fileName) {
    jsons[fileName] = require('app/content/' + fileNames[i] + '.json');
    return jsons;
  }, {});
}
```

Which you can use to build the data object for all your templates:

```
var data = requireJsons(['intro', 'header', 'faq', 'features', 'footer']);

gulp.task('html', function() {
  return gulp.src('./app/templates/*.hbs')
    .pipe(handlebars(data, {
      // ...
```

---

If you always need to load all the json files from `app/content` directory, you can use [readdirSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options) to obtain all .json file names and then pass them to `requireJsons`:

```
var path = require('path');
var fileNames = fs.readdirSync('app/content')
  .filter(function(fileName) {
    return path.extname(fileName) === '.json';
  });
var data = requireJsons(fileNames);
```

Of course, if speed is important, you could combine the two into one method that loads the jsons and builds the `data` object in a single pass.

---

Another option is to possibly compile each template individually and pass appropriate data into each compilation. A tool like [gulp-foreach](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-foreach) would be helpful.